# Tunneling during collisions using PhysicsWorld in cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, chipmunk

I am trying to use accelerometer in my game to control movement of an object on the scene. I used the PhysicsWorld from cocos2d-x to created my scene

```
auto scene = Scene::createWithPhysics();
```

And used pretty much everything according to the tutorial: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Physics

However, my object has a very bad penetration in the edgeBox. My update rate for moving the object by accelerometer is 60 fps. I was wondering if changing time steps in physics world cold solve this problem. But, I'm not sure how could I do that.
I appreciate it if you could share any comment you have regarding this issue.

PS. I am using cocos2d-x v3.0. Every details that I set up my Sprite and edgebox is similar to the example described in wiki. The only difference is that on every onAcceleration event I run this:

```
double xAcc = acc->x * 200.0;    
double yAcc = acc->y * 200.0;
PhysicsBody * pinguBody = pingu->getPhysicsBody();
pinguBody->setVelocity(Vect(xAcc, yAcc));
```

Comment: usually "continuous" collision detection helps in such a case, I believe chipmunk has such a setting for the body

Comment: AFAIK Chipmunk doesn't support CCD. You're going to have to recreate the same behavior with your own code. I usually use ray-casting between two points to check if the ray intersects with the body of an object that the sprite shouldn't go through.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Valerio. Yeah, I realized that's the case as well. Anywasys, I switched to Box2D at the end and the problem was solved.